# using subroutinization to trade data between fortran programs

Tags: performance, fortran, subroutine

I have two independent (and large) fortran programs that I need to exchange data back and forth between. They are environment simulators (lets call them A and B) that need to trade a few arrays worth of data every time-step until the simulation is complete. The solution I came up with was to transform B into a subroutine that gets called by A every time-step, and data gets passed through parameters. Because B is so large, initializing it every time-step is slow.

Is there a way to keep B in memory so A doesn't have load everything back into memory each time? Are there other ways to make the subroutine call not so slow?

Is there a more efficient way to exchange data between independent fortran programs in a synchronized way without subroutinization?

Comment: I could imagine to make both just a different branch of one program and bind them with MPI, shared memory threads, coarrays...

Comment: @VladimirF Could you expand on how to use shared memory threads in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the MPI approach, you also could design an object (a derived type) which contains all the variables program B needs to know in order to remember its state between calls. Then you should divide up the functionality of program B into three routines:

- initialization routine (called before the first timestep in A)
- main routine (called at each time step in A)
- optional: destruction (called after the last time step in A).

Every time you call any of those routines from program A, you pass them the derived type with the variables. In the first call, they get initialized, in the subsequent calls they are used.

So program A would look like:

```
type(bdata) :: myb
...
call initialize_b(myb)
do ii = 1, ntimesteps
  ...
  call main_b(myb, data)
  ...
end do
call destruct_b(myb)
```

The type `bdata` must contain everything program B needs to remember, something like:

```
type :: bdata
  integer, allocatable :: whatever(:)
  ...
end type bdata
```

And the routines in the module with the functionality of program B would be like:

```
!> First initialization of B (slow).
subroutine initialize_b(myb)
  type(bdata), intent(out) :: myb
  ...
end subroutine initialize_b


!> Process data comming from program A.
subroutine main_b(myb, data)
  type(bdata), intent(inout) :: myb
  ...
end subroutine main_b
```

If you need only one instance of the program B, you can do the same trick by turning the program B into a module with module variables stroring its state (instead of the fields of the derived type). But whatever for whatever solution go, you have to separate the initialization part somehow, to make sure it is executed only once.

Comment: This solution makes sense to me but would require a lot of effort to implement because the programs are so large/complex. Without the code, does anyone have an intuition as to whether this approach would be faster/slower than message passing with MPI?

Comment: It does not require any communication, so it should be faster, especially if a big chunk of data must be exchanged between the programs. (Instead sending data around using MPI, you would pass "pointers" using subroutine calls.)

Comment: again, this would take an enormous amount of code rewriting to implement correctly. Can similar results be achieved by compiling with the option to "SAVE" all variables between subroutine invocations of "B" and have "B" jump to the point after initialization for all time-steps after the first?